# search queries in nodejs and mongodb and populated data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a web app that's written in nodejs and mongodb, i have the following two models

```
   var TeacherSchema = new Schema({
       school_id:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'}],
       name: String,
       subjects: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subject'}],
       });


 var SubjectSchema = new Schema({
     title : String,
     school_id:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School'}]
     });
```

i wrote an api that searches throw the teacher or subjects

```
 router.get("/field-teacher-subject", function (req, res) {
var   school_id= req.query.schoolId;
Subject.find(school_id:'school_id,function (err, subjects) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({status: "error", message: err.message});
    } else {
        var sub_array=[];
        for(var q in subjects){
            sub_array.push(subjects[q]._id);
        }
        Teacher.find({subjects:{$in :sub_array }},{first_name:true, father_name:true, last_name : true, subjects:true}).populate('subjects')
            .exec(function(tech) {
                console.log("hello: ");
                var subjeto = [];
                if(tech){
                    for(var p in tech){
                        subjeto.push(tech[p].subjects);
                    }
                }
                res.json({status: "success", message: "subjects returned", 
            items: tech});
            }).catch(function(err){
                if(err){
                    res.json({status:"error",
                      message:"error occurred"+err.message});
                    return;
                }
            });
    }
}).limit(parseInt(req.query.max));
});
```

THIS RETURNS null when i search for a name,
what is the best way to solve this

Comment: Search for a  name where? I see nothing here trying to match a name. Which name? The teacher name? Not really all that clear what you are asking.

Comment: teacher name or subject name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what you are asking but your code has few errors. Let's clean up your code, shall we?

```
router.get("/field-teacher-subject", function (req, res) {
    // get subjects
    Subject
        .find({ school_id: req.query.schoolId })    // 1st argument is an object
        .limit(parseInt(req.query.max))             // should go before 
        .exec(function (err, subjects) {            // use .exec()
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.json({ status: "error", message: err.message });
            }
            // get subject IDs
            var sub_array = subjects.map(function (subject) { return subject._id; });
            // get teachers assigned to subjects
            Teacher
                .find({ subjects: { $in: sub_array }})
                .select('first_name father_name last_name subjects')
                .populate('subjects')
                .exec(function(err, teachers) {     // 1st argument is an error
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.json({status: "error", message: err.message });
                    }
                    var subjeto = teachers.map(function (teacher) { return teacher.subjects; });

                    res.json({status: "success", message: "subjects returned", items: teachers  });
                });
    });
});
```

Useful links:

- See 3rd example in [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) on how to use `.limit()` and `.exec()`.
- [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- You tried to use `.exec()` like `.then()` and `.catch()` in your second query